# Custom protocol on top of ktor that is not HTTP or websockets with native support?

Tags: ktor

I am writing a server/client application with its own custom protocol. It is asynchronous which fits with Kotlin and Ktor.

I wonder how I can use Ktor to implement my own protocol on top on ktor-server-cio engine with full support for kotlin/Native.
Where could I find documentation or examples, I can't find it in the documentation, also it is hard to see what is and is not dependent of kotlin/JVM?

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `CIO` engine for a server doesn't support Kotlin/Native yet.

You can use [sockets API](https://ktor.io/docs/servers-raw-sockets.html) from the `ktor-network` module, which does support Kotlin/Native, to implement client and server for your custom protocol on top of TCP or UDP.

As an example, take a look at [rsocket-kotlin](https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-kotlin) library where transports are implemented based on Ktor.